# Is REPLICATE DATA pattern good option to minimize synchronous micro-services communication?

Tags: microservices

In a world of microservices, often one microservice needs to invoke another, synchronous or asynchronous way.

In the case of synchronous way of communication, I have understood that it affects the availbility of services, as both services need to be available during calls.

To minimize this synchronous way of communication, one possible solution is to have DATA REPLICATION at client service. The client service also up-to-date data by listening to events published by services.

According to me, this is not a good choice as we are duplicating data and it might become stale and also database overhead.

what will be the best suitable scenario when the above pattern will be the best suit?

Answer (score 1):

Microservices are distributed systems.  This means that they are constrained by the CAP theorem, which basically means you have a choice between:

- Sacrifice availability to preserve consistency: this would (among other things) lead to one service invoking functionality in another in a synchronous way.  If the other service is unavailable, so is all functionality in this service which depends on that service's functionality.
- Sacrifice consistency to preserve availability: you build services to be autonomous and not depend on other services being up.  This leads in fairly short order to services not sharing databases and to asynchronous replication of data (because if service A has synchronously replicated data from service B, then service B being down doesn't affect A's availability, but A being down affects B's availability): with asynchronous replication, the best you can hope for is eventual consistency.

The choice between those two (if you happen to have the ability to freeze the entire universe if there's a network partition, you might be able to sacrifice partition tolerance for consistency and availability) is ultimately a business question (it's worth noting that there's a continuum of approaches between those extremes).  How much are you spending on storage and on designing an (arguably) more complex system vs. how much are you losing by being unavailable?

It should be noted that the universe is inherently eventually consistent: the sun could have gone supernova a few minutes ago and we can't know it for a few minutes more.

As for the concern about duplicated data: chances are the data is already duplicated (backups) and in any database worth using the data is duplicated (the write-ahead log).

As for situations, it's a lot harder to think of a situation where aiming for strong consistency is strictly the most suitable option.

But for an example, consider a chain of coffee shops.  We have a cash register service and we have a loyalty/rewards service.  Data from the loyalty/rewards service is needed by the cash register (if a customer is redeeming a "50% off a latte" reward you'd want the register to know that it's valid), and every transaction (at least those with a loyalty ID) at the register should be known by the rewards service.

If we want the reward redemptions to be consistent, then it implies that if the loyalty/rewards service is inaccessible from the register, no rewards can be redeemed.  There's a nonzero chance that a customer who can't redeem a reward just walks out (and a further nonzero chance that they never get coffee from you again).

Conversely, if we want both services to have a consistent view then we're demanding that if the power's out at any store we can't determine new rewards, or if the loyalty/rewards service is inaccessible from the register, no new sales can be made.

The solution is for both services to maintain the data they need to function, even if another service controls updates to that data.  They'll eventually catch up.  In the case of reward redemption, assuming the unavailability happens rarely enough, it may even be desirable to have the cash register perform a preliminary validation and if that passes, assume that the reward is valid and submit it later to the loyalty/reward service.